# check if the image is already downloaded?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im using unity3d `www` to download an image from a web server and stored it to my local storage. The only checking that I have is `System.IO.File.Exists()` to check if its already downloaded. My problem is that it will not re-download when the image from the web server is updated or replace with the same exact filename. I also tried `www.responseHeaders` but it will only be available once the image is downloaded. I know about assetbundle but I don't want to create assetbundle for just one image.

**Edit:**

Here is my code, slightly modified. Fist I connect to webserver to fetch all the projects data including the image url as an array of data in json type. Then i will loop through that array which has the url of the image to download.

```
void ConnectToWeb()
{
    StartCoroutine(AppManager.Instance.WebRequest("http://www.google.com",
        (AppManager.HttpResponse callback) =>
        {
            if (callback.ResponseCode == 0 || callback.ResponseCode != 200)
            {
                throw new ArgumentException(callback.Error);
            }
            if (callback.Done == true)
            {
                StartCoroutine(LoadData(callback.JsonResponse));
            }
        })
    );
}

private IEnumerator LoadData(JsonData itemData)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < itemData["results"].Count; i++)
    {
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(itemData["results"][i]["picture_name"].ToString()))
        {
            WWW www = new WWW(itemData["results"][i]["picture_url"].ToString());
        while (!www.isDone)
        {
            Debug.Log("downloaded " + (www.progress * 100).ToString() + "%...");
            yield return null;
        }
        File.WriteAllBytes(imagePath, www.bytes);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Please add the code you are using to download and save the image.

Comment: Best way to realize this would be saving a hash of the image and comparing against the web server if the hash changed. And if it changed re-download the image.

Comment: @Nico Yes, that was the first thing in my mind but I think this will be slow if there are many images. I assume these images are textures.

Comment: @Programmer Indeed. If there are many images/textures it can take quite a time. The hash comparing itself is fast though. The web Server can disclose an API for handling hash comparing. It should have the hashes pre-saved of it's images and the client can send his hash the server. The slow part would be the downloading I guess. If he really wants to write an API just for that is the other question. Cost-Use question. Maybe thinking about a ingame update mechanism would be a another option. Many games do this now.

Comment: Yes many games do it now. In Unity that's AssetBundle but OP mentioned he/she can't use that. What's left now is using hash like you mentioned or manually saving the image version on the client and the server/database.

Answer (score 0):

Use [PlayerPrefs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html)

```
public static void SetBool(string key, bool state)
{
     PlayerPrefs.SetInt(key, state ? 1 : 0);
}

public static bool GetBool(string key)
{
    int value = PlayerPrefs.GetInt(key);
    return value == 1 ? true : false;
}

void DownloadImage() {
    var isDownloaded = GetBool("IsImageDownloaded"); // <-- Check this first!
    if(!isDownloaded) {
       DownloadImageInternal(); // The real function to download an image
       SetBool("IsImageDownloaded", true);
    }
}
```

Note that System.IO.File.Exists() may or may not work for Desktop, Android and iOS apps, it is likely your app works fine in Unity Editor, but crashes when deployed to Android or iOS devices.

Comment: why wouldn't File.Exists be implemented on those platforms? They all have file systems wouldn't it be implemented?

Comment: This is close but it does **not** address OP's main issue which is to detect if the version of the image changed not just if the image is already downloaded. As for `File.Exists` issue, the only one I know is  it always returning  `true` It shouldn't crash when used on paths like `Application.persistentDataPath`. Also, make sure that the directory exist (`Directory.Exists`) before checking if the file exist.

Comment: @WeylandYutani, just try it. You will find you cannot find a single format that describes the file path which are universal for Android, iOS and desktop. Correct me if this is not the case.

Comment: @WeylandYutani, I did not find any description about version issues, this might not be the OP's intent.